# Overriding Drupal 7 comment form

Tags: drupal-7

I have the modules/comment plugin enabled.

I am trying to override the files `modules/comment/comment.tpl.php` and `modules/comment/comment-wrapper.tpl.php` in my theme so that I can edit the css/structure of the comment form.

1. I copied the above files into my theme directory and edited them.
2. Cleared development>performance>cache
3. No changes occurred on page refresh. The form remained the same.

I deleted the two files from modules/comment directory so that comment.tpl.php and comment-wrapper.tpl.php did not exist anywhere in the project, but the default form still loads regardless of the fact I deleted it everywhere?! Any ideas?? I believe it is an Acquia multisite set up.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say by the amount of information given but I think if you'd turn the [theme debugging mode](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#theme-debug) on then it would help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't remove the files from core, but I guess you know that. `Comments` is a core module, that's why it's in the `modules` directory.

If you have a multisite setup, then your theme should be in either `/sites/all/themes` or `/sites/{domain}/themes`, if it's not then your `tpl` files may not be picked up properly.

As you mention Acquia, then it's most likely you have a Varnish cache in front of your sites. It very much sounds like a caching issue.

As per @jibran, turn on theme debug, use Drush to clear your caches, and install the [Acquia Purge](https://www.drupal.org/project/acquia_purge) module to ensure that varnish clears too.

We would need more details to help further.